# Image URL being redirected to other web site

Tags: web

I am trying to use an image from an existing website in my html page. The issue is that the image is not getting resolved correctly, Even when I hit the image URL directly on browser, its getting redirected to some other site. I have tried on all browsers but no luck.

I have heard about restricting resource using hot linking but in this case not sure whats happening. Any pointers/suggestions please.

Eg - I want to use image(http://www.acsisair.com.au/wp-content/themes/acsis-air/images/logo.png) but when hitting this URL after clearing browser cache, its being redirected to other website (http://www.nine.com.au)

Answer (score 0):

It's very, very likely a form of hotlinking protection: if you change the URL subtly to make it clearly incorrect, you get a 404 page.

That means when you enter an URL to a resource that exists, you're given a header redirect. That's not an accident.

There's likely nothing you can (or should) do to circumvent this.

Use images you can host on your own site.